# Are there relativistic theories with spacetime modelled on $\mathbb C^4$ rather than real Minkowski space $\mathbb R^4$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions, analyticity

Does anybody know of references to theories where relativity & spacetime is modelled on a (complex/Kähler) manifold which is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb C^4$ rather than $\mathbb R^4$, hence on a manifold of real dimension 8 rather than 4. I'm interested in both the classical and quantum case.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but there are works on supersymmetric models of quantum mechanics with generic Kähler manifolds as target space. See for example this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1046.pdf).

Comment: @yuggib many thanks for your comment. The paper you have linked seems really interesting, but here I'm looking for something more basic, where you basically see the current physics as a sort of realification of a more general complex structure, but without too many extra assumptions or further structure

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): We often assume in QFT that amplitudes of spacetime can be analytically continued to (parts of) the corresponding complex spacetime.

Comment: What about classical physics for instance? Is there a physical meaning to assuming, e.g. that the electromagnetic tensor is just the real part of a 2-form field on the cotangent bundle to $\mathbb C^4$ for instance? How can the extra 4 real space-time coordinate be interpreted? Any link to twistor theory perhaps?